# Rough on you vs rough with you

Tags: meaning, grammar

Which one correct? and if both are correct please explain me the meanings. 
I heard the phrase which says:
I was rough on you. 
And it made me think because I've always said "rough with you" instead.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I honestly don't think there is a huge difference.

"Rough on" to me implies a slight authority. Like a boss would be rough on his/her employee.

"Rough with" sounds more appropriate for two people who are both peers.

Finally, "rough on" is unambiguously metaphorical, while "rough with" is not. For example, "I was rough on him" definitely implies something like "I yelled/was angry at him" while "I was rough with him" could imply "I was physically rough with him".

Answer (score 1):

a 12 hour shift would be - rough on you.

A hungry angry lion would be- rough with you.